# Orchestrating graceful shutdown between halt, systemd and Commons Daemon

Tags: java, linux, daemon, systemd, apache-commons-daemon

**Please note:** Commons Daemon hasn't had a release since **2013**. So, if there is a more modern alternative for that (that's more compatible with `systemd`), then I'm all ears and open to any ideas!

---

I'm trying to get my Java 8 app deployed and running as a true Linux service managed by `systemd`. I have read through the [Commons Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) docs and I believe the way to accomplish this is as follows:

1. Write a `systemd` service unit file, say, a `/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service` file; this will allow me to manually control my app via `systemctl start myapp`, etc. and will also allow me to do things like: configure my app to start when Linux starts up, always attempt to restart if it crashes, etc.
2. I also then need to implement the `Daemon` interface (from Commons Daemon), which will allow my app to "listen" to events sent to it from `systemd` and invoke the correct Java methods when certain things happen (the app is started, stopped, restarted, Linux is shutdown, etc.).

My best attempt at such a `Daemon` impl:

```
public class MyApp implements Daemon {
    private BillingService billingService;
    private PizzaDeliveryService pizzaDeliveryService;

    public MyApp() {
        super();

        // Do NOT initialize any services from inside here.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp app = new MyApp();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(DaemonContext context) throws DaemonInitException, Exception {
        // 1. I assume this is where I do all my initializing,
        // and that I don't init anything in my default ctor above?
        billingService = new StripBillingService();
        pizzaDeliveryService = new LittleCaesarsDeliveryService();
        // etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        // 2. This is where my service starts actually doing things,
        // firing up other threads, etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        // 3. Will this respond to a Linux 'sudo shutdown -P now'
        // command?
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // 4. Where I'm supposed to actually release resources
        // and terminate gracefully.
    }
}
```

Is my understanding of the `Daemon` interface correct? Is it correct to simply instantiate a `MyApp` instance inside `main`, and then Commons Daemon take care of invoking `init(...)` and `start(...)` for me? Am I correct in *not* initializing any `MyApp` fields or doing dependency injection from the default constructor, and *instead* doing all that from inside `init(...)`?

**More importantly** (my actual question): what Linux commands will trigger the `stop(...)` method?

I ask because I intend on shutting the server down either by issuing `sudo shutdown -P now` or by `sudo halt -p` and am wondering which (if any) command will prompt `systemd` to invoke the `MyApp#stop(...)` method. **Any ideas?**

Comment: systemd sends a signal (term by default but [it's configurable](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html)) to a daemon process. A daemon process is expected to set up a signal handler which then triggers an appropriate shutdown method

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @user3159253 (+1) - but isn't that what Commons Daemon is doing for me (setting the signal handlers)? Or are you saying that there are other things I need to do (either at the Linux/systemd layer or at the app/Java layer) here? Thanks again!

Comment: In case of Apache Commons Daemon native system signals are handled by jsvc helper daemon and then translated to java process via internal parent-child protocol as described [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html#How_jsvc_works). You may also find useful [DaemonUserSignal](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/apidocs/org/apache/commons/daemon/DaemonUserSignal.html)

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification there @user3159253 (+1 again). So I *think* I'm hearing that, with my above setup, issuing a `sudo shutdown -P now` on the command line would trigger `systemctl stop myapp`, which in turn would invoke `MyApp#stop()`, **yes**?

Comment: The standard path for shutdown is to trigger the `init` daemon (systemd in your case), which then shuts down all running daemons, then unmounts all filesystems etc. Regardless of a daemon's implementation language/framework each daemon is asked to terminate. In case of systemd the procedure is described in the page systemd.kill mentioned above. Yes, `systemctl stop <daemon>` does basically the same for a particular service